# Terraform provider secret key from hcp_vault

Tags: terraform, hashicorp-vault

I have `secretkey` and `secretaccesskey` of a provider stored in `hcp_vault`, i am using the below piece of code to access it
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/hcp/latest/docs/data-sources/vault_secrets_app#secrets

```
data "hcp_vault_secrets_app" "example" {
  app_name = "example-vault-secrets-app"
}
```

In the provider i am using like this

```
provider "providername" {
  access_key = "data.hcp_vault_secrets_app.example.secrets.access_key"
  secret_key = "data.hcp_vault_secrets_app.example.secrets.secret_key"
}
```

It says that the `access_key` is not found,
it seems that the `provider` block will run first before fetching the `keys`, is my understanding right on this? how do i make this work.

Comment: The typical pattern here is to use Vault SDK bindings in your language of choice (best support is Go, then Ruby, then Python, then Rust/NodeJS/C++17) to interface between Vault and Terraform so as to retrieve the credentials from Vault and then transmit them to the Terraform provider via environment variables. This may or may not occur in a deployment pipeline (but typically does for security reasons).

Comment: As to the root cause: whether `data` resolves before a `provider` block depends on the versions of the provider(s) and Terraform, but in general newer versions of each do not support this design pattern.